# Cannot set color of Button's Label inside Menu in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-menu

If I create a [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) in SwiftUI (iOS), I cannot set the color of the Buttons inside, e.g.:

```swift
Menu("Actions") {
    Button(action: { }) {
        Label("Whatever", systemImage: "pencil")
             .background(Color.red)  // does not work
    }
    .background(Color.red)           // does not work either
    .buttonStyle(RedButtonStyle())   // does not work either
}

struct RedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label.foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

If instead of `Label`, I use `Text`, or `Image` (I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974025/674487)), it doesn't work either.

Is there any way to do it?

P.S.: there is another [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60812752/674487), but it is very generic and wider in scope.

Comment: You can't change the default `Menu`'s buttons style, colors etc. in SwiftUI 2.0. You can try to build your own custom `Menu`.

Comment: The link that you posted leads to Apple's sample code on how to create your own it with `UIKit`. Follow that and then wrap it into a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` or a `UiViewRepresentable` to make it work in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is now possible in iOS 15 by setting a `Button`'s role. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button#Assigning-a-Role)

Example:

```
Menu("Actions") {
    Button(role: .destructive, action: { }) {
        Label("Whatever", systemImage: "pencil")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I was hoping that there was a workaround for iOS 14 without resorting to UIKit. Thanks anyway. I really hate that to overcome the deficiencies of SwiftUI I have to use a higher version of the OS itself...

Comment: @noe Yeah, sometimes you just have to use UIKit for certain parts instead. I have a really recent Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135581/9607863) which I made actually to create a custom context menu. I do the Introspect with `ScrollView` thing, and then add a `UIContextMenuInteraction` with `scrollView.subviews.first!.addInteraction(/* interaction delegate instance */)`. You may find that useful to implement an iOS 14 version of the context menu.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll check it out.

Comment: I can't set the font to a custom font or color other than red

Comment: @JAHelia Although more customisation is nice, this would be an unusual UX to use something other than "plain" or red as a destructive action