# SwiftUI: How to set foregroundColor on menu button

Tags: swiftui

I would like to make a menu button red as it carries a destructive nature, but my implementation doesn't override the foreground color at all.

Code.

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {}) {
           Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
               .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
    label: {
        Text("Next")
    }
}
```

Other attempts:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {}) {
           Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
    label: {
        Text("Next")
    }
}
```

Results

[image]

Noticed that the "Delete" button is not red.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259467/cannot-set-color-of-buttons-label-inside-menu-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about older iOS but it's possible from iOS 15

```
Menu("Actions") {
    Button(role: .destructive, action: { }) {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvYND.png)

Comment: introduced in iOS 15.0 / macOS 12.0 is correct.